# Tokens in menu link and title

Tags: navigation, 9, tokens

[`menu_token`](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module is working fine to achieve the purpose. Does the module [`token_filter`](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) has this functionality? I can use tokens in wysiwyg using `token_filter` but cannot make it working for menu title or url since there is no setting I could find. Since [the comment in drupal issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2903336#comment-12806556) says that it was solved using `token_filter` module, I want to know the way it was achieved.

Answer (score 1):

No, not by itself. The Token Filter module's functionality adds a token *input filter* to text formats in Drupal. The only field types that can use text formats are the 3 *Text (formatted)* field types, not the *Link* field type.

One can only speculate on the comment's solution you refer to. Text Formats/Input filters are designed to allow HTML input that should be filtered for presentation. It would be an odd-use-scenario to apply that to a link field.

Comment: Any alternate to `menu_token` module?

Answer (score 0):

Approach to solve the problem-

1. Loop through menu links (optionally title) in custom module
2. Process the tokens using `\Drupal::token()->replace()` method